# "this" keyword behaves differently when using arrow functions with jQuery callbacks

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I have a table with multiple rows, and on each row, there is an `edit` and `delete` button.

In short, when an edit button is triggered with class `.edit`,  a form pops-up.  Along with the class name, I have also included a unique `id` like `id="edit-32"`, where the number changes depending on what row the user clicks on.

The problem I am trying to solve is to capture the id attributes number after the dash. Previously, in ES5, I have simply used `this` keywoard to target the current element being clicked. But in ES6, `this` keywoard is refereing to the class environment.

ES5 approach (returns unique ID)

```
    //  Open edit form
    $('.edit').click(function(){

        // Return id attribute
        const id = $(this).attr('id'); 

        // print to console
        console.log(id); 
    });
```

ES6 approach (Returns undefined)

```
    //  Open edit form
    $('.edit').click(() => {

        // Return id attribute
        const id = $(this).attr('id'); 

        // print to console
        console.log(id); 
    });
```

Is there a way I can make arrow functions work with similar approach to ES5?

Comment: This is what arrow functions are for and what makes them unique. They don't generate a `this` and `this` remains the one from the context in which it is called. From MDN: "An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and **does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target**. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors."

Comment: Keep using `function`, because you don't need `this` to refer to the outer context here. You want it to be what jQuery forces it to be (the element).

Comment: If for some reason in the future you need an arrow function and you also need the element, `event` gets passed into the function, so you can use `event.target`.

Comment: Thanks @FrankModica, this solution is viable for my approach. I am not sure why my question has been marked duplicate. You have answered the question well, and this worked for me. I knew there was another solution, and using ES5 function deceleration is not a choice. There is always a work around. Thank god I have the knowledge otherwise I would blindly follow what others say and do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in normal functions resolves to the object that calls the function, so in this case, `this` is the element that is clicked on.

`this` in arrow functions does not define its own `this`, instead the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used.

It won't work with arrow functions in this case. You'll have to stick to bog standard functions.